# How can I test my mouse wheel click with windows 7

Tags: windows, mouse-wheel

My mouse wheel click seems to be behaving intermittently with my Firefox browser. But I would like to test it to verify it is a hardware issue and not a software one. How can I test my mouse wheel click with windows 7?

Answer (score 5):

Javascript can detect a middle-click.  Try this page. http://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html

If you have a non-generic mouse, the driver may include a diagnostics utility.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping windows had a  diagnostics utility. Web pages may not stay up forever.

Comment: Well, if that page goes down, you could try archive.org.  Or just use JavaScript yourself.  Though your best bet would be to just save a copy of this page if you don't want to lose the ability to do this later. The page looks pretty simple, without relying on external JavaScript.  You could also try Chrome.  Some games can use the third button.  (Or other third party software that can be downloaded.)  Or move the mouse to another computer.

Comment: If there is a software problem in the browser, this will fail too.

Comment: I just checked and the link is still working.